# Determine order of $\langle(12345),(2354)\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I'm asked to prove that the order of $H:=\langle(12345),(2354)\rangle$ is $20$, in an Algebra exercise 2nd year maths.

What I have achieved is that $20\mid |H|$ and $|H|=20,120$ since $H$ can't be the alternating group and [there are no subgroups of order 40 in $S_5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89040/no-subgroup-of-s-5-with-order-40). But I don't know how to prove $H\neq S_5$.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just calculate that $(2354)^{-1}(12345)(2354)=(13524)=(12345)^2$?

Comment: What would this imply?

Comment: That $H$ has a normal cyclic subgroup of order $5$ and hence $H=\langle (12345)\rangle \langle (2354)\rangle$ has order 20 [and is (as the solution of @tkf also shows) the Frobenius group of order $20$.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the integers modulo $5$.  Let $\alpha$ be the operation $\alpha\colon x\mapsto x+1$. Let $\beta$ be the operation $\beta\colon x\mapsto 2x$.

Then $\alpha,\beta$ generate all affine automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, which has size $20$: $$x\mapsto ax+b,$$ with $a\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $b\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

---

As pointed out by @JeanMarie, we have shifted the indices by $-1$ here, so $\alpha$ is the permutation $(01234)$ and $\beta$ is the permutation $(1243)$.

Comment: [+1] Very astute, but for an understanding of the isomorphism between the initial issue and yours, you should first explain that you shift everything by $-1$, working in $\mathbb{Z/5Z}$ with $(01234)$ and $(1243) \equiv (1248)$

Comment: A similar kind of trick was used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2407367)

Comment: It seems this is a very nice answer. Unfortunately, I haven't studied automorphisms.

Comment: @moqui No problem, an automorphism is just a bijective group homomorphism. It is as common for group theory as prime numbers for number theory.

Comment: @moqui Think of the maps $x\mapsto ax+b$ with $a\neq 0$ as a particular subset of permutations of $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  You need to check that such functions are closed under composition and inverse - then you know they are a subgroup.  There are $20$ such functions ($4$ choices for $a$ and $5$ choices for $b$).  You also need to check that these are distinct as permutations ($ax+b=a'x+b'$ for all $x$ implies  $a=a', b=b'$).  Then you can conclude that $\alpha,\beta$ generate a subgroup of order $20$.  With the shift of $-1$ in index, you can identify $\alpha,\beta$ with your two permutations.